# spring-integration aggregate responses from outbound-gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration, aggregator

I am looking to combine the responses from two webservice calls. the aggregation would happened based on a key value in the responses.

ws1,ws2(responses from ws1 and ws2 are passed to aggregator)--->aggregator--->response.
I return the following code. The aggregator is not being invoked, not sure what I am missing.

```
 <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="marshallingGateway1" request-channel="RequestChannel1" reply-channel="replyChannel"
                             uri="https://abc:8080/" message-sender="messageSender"
                             marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller">
        <int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-ws:outbound-gateway>
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="marshallingGateway2" request-channel="RequestChannel2" reply-channel="replyChannel"
                             uri="https://abc:8080/" message-sender="messageSender"
                             marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller">
        <int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </int-ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-ws:outbound-gateway>


    <int:aggregator id="responseAggregator" input-channel="replyChannel" ref="responseAggregator" message-store="messageStore" send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"/>

    <bean id="messageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>
    <bean id="responseAggregator" class="abc.cbd.ResponseAggregator"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting up any correlation between the two results.

By default, a header `correlationId` is used by the default correlation strategy.

You also need a `ReleaseStrategy`. It can be as simple as `release-strategy-expression="size == 2"`.

The default release strategy uses `sequenceSize` and `sequenceNumber` headers.

If you are using a publish-subscribe channel to send the same message to the two gateways, set the `apply-sequence` property to `true` and then you don't need a custom release or correlation strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Gary. I added the release strategy and it is still the same. the message to the gateways are different. A request parameter is different for the gatways.

Comment: You need something to correlate the 2 results into a group for release. Let's say you set some header (`foo`) to `bar` for both messages then they will be grouped and the release strategy will be consulted (e.g. `correlation-stratgey-expression="headers['foo']"`. As I said, the standard correlation strategy uses the `correlationId` header - you need to set it to the same value for each message (it can be done before the gateways by whatever sends the original messages). Or if you can correlate on something in the responses, that will work too.

Comment: Got it. Could you point me to a sample where the release strategy is with something in the responses.

Comment: My requirement is, the response from ws1 is key-abc, value1-123 and response from ws2 is key-abc, value 456. I need to combine the responses and create an object/JSON which says {key:"abc", value1:"123","value2"456"}. the WS1 and ws2 are called multiple times.

Comment: If the responses are XML, you can use an `#xpath` SpEL function to correlate on the key `correlation-strategy-expression="#xpath(...)"` - see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xml.html#xpath-spel-function). There is also `#jsonPath`. With unmarshalled XML, you can use a simple expression on the payload `...expression="payload.key"` will call `getKey()` on the payload object. If it's unmarshalled to a `Map`, use `"payload['key']"`.

Comment: Thank you Gary I have written a custom correlate strategy. But it is being called only for the 1st response but not for the second response. Can we open a chat for this.

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the flow; if you still have questions after doing that; sure, we can chat; there's a Spring Integration room on gitter.

Comment: On the DEBUG mode, there is no flow after the release strategy.

Comment: Edit your question to show your current configuration.

Comment: Edited the question with new configuration

Comment: You need to show the debug log too - your code/configuration looks odd in that your correlation method takes a `RetrieveResponse` but your aggregator takes a collection of `Response` and creates a `RetrieveResponse` object but returns void! Correlation is done before aggregation and the result of the aggregation should be the aggregated object.

Comment: I was trying to edit some values. The Correlation method takes Response as the input. The release method send a false and the program just sits there. The aggregator is not called after that. Am I missing a poller ?

Comment: No you don't need a poller; as I said, I need to see a DEBUG log, and an aggregator with a void return makes no sense to me - it produces no aggregated result.

Comment: Hi Gary, Added the Debug log. sorry for the delay

Comment: A few observations: `Channel 'application.responseChannel' has 2 subscriber(s)` - it's a little brittle to rely on round-robin distribution of the splitter output - it would be better to use a router there. Your log doesn't match your configuration - the initial message is sent to `requestChannel` (lower case `r`) which seems to be the input channel of the first SOAP gateway. The reply from that goes to `responseChannel` which should be the input to your splitter. That seems to go nowhere, which implies the splitter returned nothing. I can't help with mismatched log/config.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the configurations for different reasons. I might have messed up the editing

Comment: Added the complete configuration and the log

Comment: Remove the `responseChannel` from the inbound gateway - you have two consumers on that channel - the inbound gateway and the splitter. That's why the first response is "lost" - you don't need  a reply channel there. I am also not comfortable that you are relying on round robin distribution from the splitter. If you have an exception on the first leg, you will be out of sync when processing the next message. Use a router to route the splits to the transformers.

Comment: thanks Gary. Will correct the inbound gateway and will include a router